# DNS server on VPS that itself is a third-level domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

For the sake of clarity lets say I have

```
registrar.com 
hoster.com
myvps.com (my first VPS)
s2.myvps.com (my second VPS)
```

`registrar.com` delegates `myvps.com` to hoster's DNS servers (`ns1.hoster.com`, `ns2.hoster.com`).

Inside the hoster.com's admin panel I created A record pointing my first VPS` IP to myvps.com

Then I created s2.myvps.com zone and created A record that points at my second VPS` IP. It all seems to be working.

1) With that in mind, how wise would that be to run s2.myvps.com as a DNS server so that the users of s2.myvps.com could manage the whole web-site creation process inside the Virtualmin admin panel without the need to write DNS records manually in hoster.com?

2) Regardless of how wise my idea is, how would I do that? Do I just delegate newdomain.com to ns1.s2.myvps.com and ns2.s2.myvps.com and those DNS servers would automatically be found based on A records that I have already created in hoster.com?

Answer (score 4):

An `NS` record is a DNS resource record, like any other.
DNS is the [Honey Badger (pNSFW)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r7wHMg5Yjg) - It does not care what server you delegate to, so long as (a) the NS record points to a valid hostname, and (b) it is possible to resolve that hostname into an IP address so your resolver knows where to send the query.

The second part of your question basically boils down to "How do I set up and administer a DNS server?", which is ***FAR*** beyond the scope of what we can explain in a Server Fault answer.
The fact that you're asking this (without actually saying the words) makes me think you do not fully understand what you're asking, and I would suggest you stick with your current DNS provider until you have gained the requisite knowledge to set up and administer a DNS server.

---

If you still want to set up and administer your own DNS server I ***STRONGLY*** suggest you pick up a copy of [DNS and BIND](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) and become intimately familiar with it prior to attempting to set up and administer your own DNS server.  You should start small by running an internal DNS server for your home.

DNS is not hard, but without proper experience and knowledge you can make a complete disaster of it, and the consequences of that disaster can affect more than just your domain.